# How can I configure nano to save every 10 seconds?

Tags: automation, nano

I need to have my `nano` editor autosave every 10 seconds or some specific time period. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make `nano` to autosave the file that you are editing at a specific time period. You can save a file everytime when you want without exiting from `nano` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>("O" from "Omega", not zero) or <kbd>F3</kbd>.

But, don't worry, automatically saves backups. See https://manual.cs50.net/nano/#__save_files:

> If you have been using `nano`, you may see files with the "`.save`"
>   extension appearing in directories in which you are working. If you
>   are editing a file (let's call it "`hello.c`") on a server and somehow
>   your connection to the server is lost, whether because you closed the
>   terminal window or you lost your connection to the internet or some
>   other unknown reason, **`nano` will automatically save a backup** of
>   the state of the file in a new file with a "`.save`" extension (e.g.
>   "`hello.c.save`"). So, when you log back onto server, don't worry that
>   you've lost everything you've been working on because you hadn't saved
>   for an extended period of time, you can simply open up the "`.save`"
>   file and then continue from where you left off, and when you go to
>   save the file, you can save it with the name of the original file
>   (without the "`.save`" extension). Don't rely entirely on this though,
>   such as thinking you can just close your terminal window without
>   saving because `nano` has got you covered, because in a very few cases
>   the file is not correctly created.
>
> If a "`.save`" file already exists and you open up the file without
>   the "`.save`" extension, and your connection is lost again, `nano`
>   will save the file with a "`.save.1`" extension, incrementing the
>   number at the end of the extension for each time. If you have open a
>   file without a name and lose your connection, the file will
>   automatically be saved with the name "`nano.save`".

That being said, I do not see any reason of concern for autosaving files in `nano`.

Comment: Source: https://manual.cs50.net/nano

Comment: Wow. That's pretty blatant plagiarism.